# How do I fix this PHP download script, which is corrupting files?

Tags: php, download

I have a force-download script that produces good results with PDF and plain text, and is semi-OK with ZIP archives (they work in Windows, not in Linux).  However, application files and images all fail.  These make up the vast majority of the files I must handle.  Zipping all downloads, as I've seen suggested on similar topics here, is not an option.

The failing files download to their full size, and are written to disk under the correct name.  Attempts to open them result in a error message, which differs between types.  Comparing downloaded files to their originals in *hexdump*, I can see that the script inserts the following characters at the start of each downloaded file:

```
ef bb bf
```

The downloaded file then reproduces the original until it stops at its specified size - so the original's last 6 characters are always missing.

Unfortunately I know nothing about how binary files are made up, what these characters might mean, or how/why the script is inserting them.

This is the script as-is:

```
$file = '94.ppt';
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/relative/path/";
$full_path = $path.$file;
if ($fd = fopen ($full_path, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($full_path);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($full_path);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "txt":
            header("Content-type: text/plain");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "jpg":
            header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "ppt":
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        default;
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
```

The development system is PHP 5.3.2-1 on Apache 2.2.14 (Ubuntu).  The production host is PHP 5.2.9 on Apache 2.0.63 (some type of Linux).

Comment: not sure if it is a typo in your post or actual code "default;" should be : not ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EF BB BF` is the UTF-8 encoding [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). I suspect there is some configuration option to turn off the BOM.

**Edit:** File editors should allow you to turn off the BOM when saving an file in relevant character encodings (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's getting output because the script (or some script it includes) was saved as UTF-8, and the editor prepended a BOM that's now getting passed through to the output.  A config setting wouldn't fix that

Comment: A config setting in the editor would :-) Also, the OP mentioned that images are failing so it cannot be a BOM prefixed source file.

Comment: Touche.  :)  I was thinking about PHP settings, ather than editor settings.

Comment: I was not clear in my answer either so thanks for your comment :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, the script now works perfectly. The cause was an encoding setting in Notepad++. It would have taken me an age - if ever - to find this on my own.

Answer (score 5):

Your PHP script file seems to be encoded in [UTF-8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) that is right at the begin of the file before the opening `<?php` delimiter. These bytes are sent before your actual output and thus corrupting your data.

You just need to remove it and configure your editor not to use the BOM for UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks guys, the script now works perfectly. The cause was an encoding setting in Notepad++. It would have taken me an age - if ever - to find this on my own.

Comment: @hnmcc: This is a common problem especially because UTF-8 doesn’t require a BOM as there is only one byte order – well, except for automatic encoding detection.

Comment: I have an image file injected with some kind of corruption, maybe it is bom.  However, I never edited the file.  The file without the injected stuff was uploaded through a web app and downloaded through FTP, with no weird codes before or after.  But the weird codes, making the file corrupt, appeared when downloading through a web app that conceals is the file's on the web.  The file is being read by fread, in a loop of 1024 bytes at a time,sent to the buffer on each loop.  Somehow the corruption happens there, but only if I have edited the php file containing the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`EF BB BF` is the standard UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Some people have [reported](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/4442/attachments-download-problem/p1) that this happens when some of your PHP files that you include in the script are UTF-8 encoded; some versions of PHP react to this by sending out the UTF-8 byte order marker. The link above suggests calling `ob_start()` at the beginning of the script and `ob_end_clean()` before you start pushing out the contents of your file -- this way the byte order marker gets caught in the output buffer.

Also, you could simply use `fpassthru` to pipe your file to the output instead of reading and writing in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for this: at the moment I'm under pressure to get something - anything - that works.  But I do plan to look at the project again later in the summer.