# PHP download file from base64 without BOM

Tags: php

I've a script that retrieve a file base64 encoded from a web service.

I can view the file also from ufficial panel provided by the application.

Download the file from ufficial panel i get it as expected. (it's a file.xml.p7m with digital signature inside it)

But using my script to retrieve the same file from web service (who provide the file as base64 response) i use this script to download it. But file is not equal as downloaded from ufficial panel.

My script insert implicit BOM. How can i prevent it?

my ajax_get_xml.php

```
//retrieve base64 file from web server

$fileBase64 = get_base64_encoded_file_from_ws();

$fileDecoded = base64_decode($fileBase64);

header(‘Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxxxx.xml"’);
header(‘Content-type: “text/xml”; charset=“utf8”’);
header(‘Connection: close’);

echo $fileDecoded;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the script itself that has a BOM at the start of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix this PHP download script, which is corrupting files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328750/how-do-i-fix-this-php-download-script-which-is-corrupting-files)

Comment: (_“my ajax_get_xml.php”_ - not really; those curly quotes would only cause syntax errors …)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes i'm sure. I'm using notepad++ and show me: WINDOWS (CR LF) - UTF-8